# Is there a way to save the current GIMP edit history as a script?

Tags: gimp, text, script, history

Is there a way to export the edit history so I can use it in a script-fu?

Comment: Since the answer seems to be "no", I figured I'd mention that what you're describing sounds like Photoshop Actions... Or the Scripting Listener plugin for PS. Actions are straight up Macros recorded inside PS. Actions can be ran from scripts and they can trigger scripts too... Or just on their own without any scripting involved. The scripting listener plugin is a thing that basically logs things you do in PS you do as blocks of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (and I have seen many people try to implement such a capability). One problem is that there is not a one-to-one mapping between UI actions and the script-fu API (and there are many things that can only be done in the UI). Another is that you would need to keep a lot of data (think about a stroke with the pain brush...). A third is that you need to take in account all the scripts/plugins...